# How to Post asp:FormView in ASP.NET WebForms by ajax of Jquery with model binding?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, formview

I'm using FormView of ASP.NET WebForms and this form is posted to a method by clicking on a button inside FormView:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" ClientIDMode="Static" 
    ValidationGroup="projectmodification" runat="server" 
    Text="Save" CommandName="Update" />
```

and here is posted method

```
public void UpdateMethod(Project project){
}
```

It's working well now, but i don't know how to post this form to this kind of method by using ajax of Jquery and keep model binding feature (the values are auto populated to Project model).

Could you please show me the way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use web methods.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateMethod(Project project)
{
  ...
}

public class Project
{
  public string ProjectName{get;set;}
  public string ProjectDesc{get;set;]
}
```

in your jQuery Code:

```
var project = new Object();
project.ProjectName = "First Project";
project.ProjectDesc = "Project Description";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "YourPage.aspx/UpdateMethod",
    data: "{'project':"+JSON.stringify(project)+"}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```